# Fantasy book: Street kid who trains to become a dueler

Tags: story-identification

Relatively new book about a "street kid" who gets a corrupted nobleman sponsor who sends him to duelling school / Warrior school.

- Uses Saber and knife
- Got robotic sparring partners which wizards of old had created.
- Protagonist gets kicked out for illegal duelling or something.
- Protagonist has some type of instinctive magic that makes him unstoppable.
- Protagonist becomes an assassin / Illegal dueller.
- Antagonist's sponsor frames him for killing the duke and becomes the next duke.
- A nobleman sponsor a young street kid into dueling school. And secretly trains him into an assassin.
- This kid trains in sabre/knife fencing but gets kicked out in the end.
- They got magical constructs that wizards of old made.
- This kid is that a girl gets raped and her uncle's inn gets burned out.
- The nobleman and the kid gets into another country where they assassinate a person to start a war. Kid kills a big cat and gets a new coat.
- The kid ask the nobleman for help and the nobleman seduces and later sends her to a brothel. This causes a falling out.
- The kid/man starts going down a bad path, starts killing for hire, illegal dueling, etc.
- The kid for somereason got the blood of a body guard of mages. They have been gone since they helped to kill the mages.
- the nobleman uses him to get the duke killed when the kid acts as his bodyguard.
- The nobleman/new duke, sentencing him to death, kid get let go or freed.
- The prostitue and him decides in leaving that country.
- He leaves first, his girl leaves later and that ship gets taken by pirates.
- book 2/3 is about him chasing pirates.

Comment: I remember more: "The street kid/ orphan gets in to the dueling school thanks to the nobleman. He meets  a girl who thanks to him gets raped. When the kid ask the nobleman for help, then he sends the girl to a brothel." probably makes no sense since im rambling, but something like that :P

Answer (score 2):

This is the *[**Society of the Sword**](https://www.goodreads.com/series/105424-society-of-the-sword)* series by Duncan M. Hamilton

From an [Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3220V2AJPLH63/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=148101322X) of the first book [The Tattered Banner](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17557803-the-tattered-banner),

> The hero, Soren, is plucked from a starving street urchin’s life by a
>   famous nobleman to attend Ostia’s prestigious Academy of
>   Swordsmanship.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1831142553?book_show_action=true) on goodreads mentions Alessandra,

> [a] *barmaid turned whore*

Answer (score 1):

Talon of the Silver Hawk by Raymond E. Feist has some similarity with the book your describing

it isnt an exact match but you may be confusing 2 or more books together

IIRC there were magical constructs used in training

and there was an assassination plot

Comment: Details of what matches and what doesn't?

Comment: Not the same book series. but alot seems the same.